# Strange Printing on arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm testing the performances/hitches for References over copies of an array. I have the following code:

```
function ScoreWords($Value){
    $WordList = array(
        "Amazing" => 1,
        "Value" => 300,
        "Elements" => 30,
        "Another" => 0

    );

    if (array_key_exists($Value,$WordList)){
        return $WordList[$Value];
    }

}

$array = ["Value","Another",1,2,3,4];
echo implode(',', $array), "<br>";

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    ScoreWords($value);
}
echo implode(',', $array), "<br>";

foreach ($array as $value) {
    ScoreWords($value);
}    
echo implode(',', $array), "<br>";
```

But it seems, the code pasted above works semi-fine. Output is:

> Value,Another,1,2,3,4
>
> Value,Another,1,2,3,4
>
> Value,Another,1,2,3,3

I found this by mistake as imploding was not actually necessary, but this sparks the question. Why is there a duplicated value for the final print rather than the correct value of `4`? regardless of what the content of the array is. It seems to duplicate the second from last element as the last element?

Comment: Read #1 in this list of [10 Most Common Mistakes PHP Programmers Make](http://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make)

Comment: @MarkBaker: Wow.  That perfectly explains the exact issue here! :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that after your 1st `foreach`, `$value` is a reference to the last element in the array.  As that loop progressed it was a reference to each element, until finally stopping at the last one.

So, when the 2nd `foreach` runs, `$value` is *still* a reference.  As that loop runs, it updates `$value`, which in turn, updates the last element in the array.

When it gets to the last element, it was set to 3 from the previous loop iteration.  So, that's why it's set to 3 at the end.

To fix this, `unset($value);` after your first `foreach`.

Comment: `var_dump($array)` will show that element is indeed a reference

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that you have to `unset` the value when you pass it by reference:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    ScoreWords($value);
}
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

> **Warning** Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even
>   after the foreach loop. It is recommended to destroy it by unset().

[Foreach reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)